# Cannot purchase Support from Google -- no button or link

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-console

I'm following Google's instructions for purchasing Silver support, but there's no button or link for changing my current Bronze level of support to Silver. I think my appengine app has been integrated into Cloud Console -- I login to Cloud Console and I see my app. Also, on the appengine console, under Application Settings in the Cloud Integration part of the page, it says, "The project was created successfully. See the Basics section for more details." It doesn't offer a button for integrating my app with Cloud Console because, I think, this has already happened.

The instructions say to select my app in Cloud Console and then select Support from the left menu. The page I get tells me my current support level ("Your support package: Bronze"), but it offers no way to buy a different level of support.

Any pointers on how I can purchase support? I want to give Google $150/month for this, and they seem not to want to take my money.

Comment: What did Google say when you asked them about this (during the research you did before posting to StackOverflow)?

Comment: Google's stated support channel for appengine matters IS StackExchange. Lacking a direct channel to Google (only available through the paid support I'm trying to buy), I posted where I'm supposed to post. But thanks for the snide remark.

Comment: `Google's stated support channel for appengine matters IS StackExchange` Not quite; for Bronze, [you can open a ticket](https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_billing). And while you might be directed toward StackExchange, your specific post here is still considered off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, your post is considered off-topic by admdrew, anyway.